# Eclipse error on opening: Linux Mint 12

Tags: linux-mint, eclipse

I've installed Eclipse with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

or when I install via the synaptic manager.

Unfortunately, when I open up Eclipse I get this error:

```
org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.setVisibleEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.setVisibleEditor(EditorManager.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager$5.runWithException(EditorManager.java:972)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3563)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$33.runWithException(Workbench.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3563)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Some succeeded by renaming the ~/.eclipse folder (e.g.

```
sudo mv ~/.eclipse ~/.eclipse.bak
```

Note, all plugins will be disabled and you will need to re-install them.

Others (incl. me) did not succeed by doing this. In this case, you have to remove/uninstall the whole platform. You then have to download the package [from the official website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads) (and then move for example the extracted package to your `/usr/share` folder).

Re-installing the IDE via `apt-get` probably won't work.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is something wrong with [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) environment variable.

Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519
Linux: http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm
Mac: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable

You need to add the path to the java folder there. After that it should work again as expected.